# Create a vector image from python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, image, canvas, vector, tkinter

I was wondering is there any way to export tkinter canvas as vector image or convert it to the vector image? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the canvas' `.postscript(...)` method to save as Encapsulated PostScript file. you can find the options for this method [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have found library called [canvasvg](https://pypi.org/project/canvasvg/). This might do the job for tkinter canvas and also for turtle canvas.